# Jettison or Kryo

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, kryo

I currently use JAXB for a project i'm working on and looking to convert my libraries archived xml to archived json, To act in my project. I figured I would use [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) as it seems it would be [easier to implement](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html) since it actually works with JAXB; however, looking at [Older benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking) in which Jettison was not included I have found [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/)   produces smaller files and Serialized and DeSerialized quicker than some alternatives.

Can anyone inform me of the key difference or otherwise how Jettison stacks up to Kryo, especially for future projects such as android applications.

EDIT:

I guess i'm looking for what produces smaller files and operates faster. Human readability can be sacrificed since I don't plan on reading the files only processing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy**)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the **[JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)** expert group.

Since you already have established JAXB mappings and are converting XML to JSON, you may be interested in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) which offers both object-to-XML and object-to-JSON mapping using the same JAXB metadata.

**Customer**

Below is a sample model with JAXB annotations.

```
package forum11599191;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    private String lastName;

    private List<String> email;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="123" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <firstName>Jane</firstName>
    <lastName xsi:nil="true"/>
    <email>jdoe@example.com</email>
</customer>
```

**Demo**

The following demo code will populate the objects from XML and then output JSON.  Note how there are no compile time dependencies on MOXy.

```
package forum11599191;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        // Unmarshal from XML
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11599191/input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        // Marshal to JSON
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**JSON Ouput**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
{
   "customer" : {
      "id" : 123,
      "firstName" : "Jane",
      "lastName" : null,
      "email" : [ "jdoe@example.com" ]
   }
}
```

A few things to note about the output:

1. Since the `id` field is a numeric type it was marshalled to JSON without quotes.
2. Even though the `id` field was mapped with `@XmlAttribute` there are no special indication of this in the JSON message.
3. The `email` property had a `List` of size one, this is properly represented in the JSON output.
4. The `xsi:nil` mechanism was used to specify that the `lastName` field had a `null` value, this has been translated to the proper null representation in the JSON output.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html

Comment: Is their a good way to export a mixed HashMap list? ie HashMap<String,Object>

Answer (score 3):

They are for somewhat different purposes:

- Jettison is for reading/writing JSON. Use it if you need to interoperte with a JSON (human-readable) data format
- Kryo is for efficient binary serialisation. Use it if you need high performance and small encoded object sizes (e.g. communication of messages in a realtime game).

Since it sounds like you are using the format to archive data, human-readability and the use of a standard long-lived format is probably more important than efficiency, so I suspect you will want to choose the JSON route.

Comment: Well both projects actually are games which is why Kryo appealed to me.